# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: is not getting called in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-signin

I upgraded GoogleSignIn SDK from 2.4.0 to 4.0.0. App works fine in iOS9. But in iOS8.4(which I am current testing in) after successful login it gets redirected to the app, but neither
`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` nor `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
 is getting called. Receiving warning as

> < FIRAnalytics/WARNING > Implementation of
>   application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please
>   add the handler into your App Delegate. Class:
>   CleverTapAppDelegateSurrogate

But I have implemented the methods. Does anyone have any idea? I read the docs and nothing specific is mentioned. Am I missing something to support iOS8 as well?

```
#if __IPHONE_9_0

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options {

   return YES; 
}

#else

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

   return YES;
}

#endif
```

Would someone direct me in the right way? Thanks in advance.
By the by I am using Xcode version 7.3.

Comment: Did you find any solution. Facing similar issue. @Alex

Comment: @RahulMishra Yes. Configured the Clevertap manually and everything starts working normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CleverTap Overrides the method  internally for DeepLinking Process.

```
  (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation
```

Configure your clever tap manually for whaterver reasons you want.

Remove this line and configure everything manually. Everything will work cool.

```
[CleverTap autoIntegrate];
```

Comment: Late but the answer is correct. After integrating manually everything started working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check wether your category override the method : - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options,if has category  method it will excuse category method your method will not excuse

Comment: No category.  In your case it should not work in iOS 9 as well.